# Passing data between driver and Windows service

Tags: c, windows, windows-services, kernel, device-driver

What is the cleanest way to pass data from device driver to windows service and back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normally achieved using [Device Input and Output Control (IOCTL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363219%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

You can define your own private control code and then send information in both directions. The function is called from user mode, i.e. the service in your case.